# Mouse listener issue in Safari 7.0

Tags: javascript, safari, scope, mousemove

I'm working on an JS application using mouse movement as the main method of interaction.

This is done by simply registering a `mousemove` listener on `window`. Each time the listener is triggered I will subtract the current position by the previous one to calculate the movement delta. The movement delta then gets interpolated on `requestAnimationFrame` so it smoothly returns to `0` if there is no mouse activity. This is very basic and I'd just expect it to work.

All is fine in Chrome and Firefox (at least) but Safari 7 (OSX 10.9) behaves quite mysteriously.

- I can hold down the left mouse button down and drag to meet the expected behaviour.
- Stranger... If I add a console.log statement in one of the event listeners and open the web inspector all suddenly works as expected.

Here's an illustration of the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uwBmI

Comment: Wild guess.  The `setInterval()` at 20ms is taking most of the CPU and thus Safari is not servicing optional mousemove events.  How to prioritize these conflicts could easily be browser-specific.  Try making the interval period much longer just as a test.  I don't have Safari here to try it myself.

Comment: @jfriend00 - It's a wise guess, however I've been testing a few different values without noticing any difference. Originally I'm using including RAF instead of setInterval.

Comment: I have this exact problem in my app in Safari 7.0.3 under Yosemite. Any chance you found a solution?